# UNITY 2D Dungeon Cralwer teleport from room to room

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I want to make a 2D Dungeon Crawler in Unity,
The rooms will be randomly generated squares
I want my player to be able to teleport from room A to room B
All of the rooms will be spawned with prefabs
Is there any way to make a link between 2 prefabs to teleport the player from room A to room B and back?

Comment: Or is there any way to transition from a room into another room without just walking trough some sort of corridor.

Comment: if you set the position of the player according to the room, will appear on the desired place

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you literally mean *teleport* the player.

In that case, have a 2D Collider with *IsTrigger* toggled on. Add a script to the collider with a **OnTriggerEnter2D()** method that update the position of any object that enters it.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D obj)
{
    obj.transform.position = new Vector2(XPosition, YPosition);
}
```

Comment: Documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html